# Плагин для слабовидящих (js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Столкнулся с необходимостью прикрутить на сайт плагин для слабовидящих.
Нашел плагин bvi ([GitHub](https://github.com/veks/button-visually-impaired-javascript)), но все мои попытки заставить это работать тщетны.

Есть ли какой-то конкретный плагин, который позволит мне сделать версию сайта для слабовидящих без изменения верстки или же мне нужно придумать свое решение (можете предложить свои идеи)?

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообще такие вещи реализовываются в CSS.

Добавляешь в `<body class="high-contrast">...</body>`

И всё что наследуется от `.high-contrast` уже делается для людей со слабым зрением.

А ещё советую изучить такую вещь как media-type он-же @media

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#media-types

Узнаешь много интересного.

Comment: Может я не совсем грамотно выразился. Нужно минимальное взаимодействие со стилями. Как по мне, лучшее решение будет в использовании Js